# JavaScript не работает в IE 11 Ошибка-DOM7011

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, localstorage

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему выпадания ошибки в ИЕ11 и заставить там же работать ЖС код. Выпадает следующая ошибка:

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For
>   more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

У меня на сайте ЖС ведёт свою работу с LocalStorage  - может из-за этого ругается и отпадает.

Причём дебаггер ИЕ11 ругается на метод `localStorage.setItem(name, value);` И выдаёт ошибку:

> Unable to get property 'setItem' of undefined or null reference

В Мозиле, Хроме, Опере всё работает без нареканий и в консоле без ошибок.

Comment: Так undefined у вас не `value`, а `localStorage`.

Comment: Да согласен, ошибся чуть. Отредактировал свой вопрос от лишней информации в нём. В целом вопрос актуален.

Comment: А какая версия IE? с точностью до цифр. может глюк в одной из версий. Я пробую в 11.420.10586.0 - все работает

Comment: Version: 11.0.9600.17843 - вот версия моего ИЕ, понял, попробую обновить ещё раз тогда ИЕ